# Changing logo color on scroll if background has the same color

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

my project (within Wordpress/elementor) has a number of .slide sections which have 100vh and 100vw.
it also has a fixed header with a svg #logoken hovering on the top of the page.

on scrolling down, the svg logo with id #logoken has to change color as determined in the .slide data attribute data-logo

i wrote the following code and the color change happens, but only for a second and in scrolling up, it doesn't work. i believe it has to do with my check for the slide positione, but i don't see how.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    //Scroll action for logo & menu colors
            
    $( window ).scroll( function(e) {
        $('.slide').each( function(){
            var theSlide = this;
            var top_of_element = $(theSlide).offset().top;
            var bottom_of_element = $(theSlide).offset().top + $(theSlide).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();
            var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();
            
            if( (top_of_element >= top_of_screen) && (top_of_element < (top_of_screen + $(theSlide).height())) ) {
            
                if ( $(theSlide).data('logo') == 'black'){
                    if(!$("#logoken").hasClass("black")){
                        $("#logoken").addClass("black");
                    }
                } 
                else{
                     if($("#logoken").hasClass("black")){
                        $("#logoken").removeClass("black");
                    }
                }
                console.log ($(this).attr('id') +" is on top: and logocolor is" + $(theSlide).data('logo'));
            }
        });
    });
    
    
});
```

this is temporary link: http://castaar.ws.webwow.be where you can see my code in action...